# Opening a worksheet in another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 workbooks "StudentID" and "Student".

In the book "StudentID" there is a sheet with a list of ID's in each row of column A.
In "Student" there are sheets labelled for each student ID listed in the workbook "StudentID".

When a student ID is clicked I require that specific worksheet for that ID to open in "Student".

This is to be written in VBA.

I cant think of anyway to enable this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please don't do this.  This is a terrible way to implement whatever it is you are trying to do.  It will NOT scale, it WILL be slow, it WILL cause you huge problems in the future.  Please use a database.  Please use another programming language.  For your sake relook at your implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as you are not including any code, I understand that all what you need are some ideas to start.

In `StudentID` (.xlsm, or any other macro-supporting extension), you have to rely on the `SelectionChange` event of the specific sheet (under `Microsoft Excel Objects`, the file called as the sheet you want to track), that is, you have to write something like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If (Not IsEmpty(Selection.Value)) Then
        On Error Resume Next
        'Selection.Value -> content of the selected cell, that is, ID
        'Here you have to write your code to open the corresponding worksheet in the Student workbook
    End If
End Sub
```

With this small help, you shouldn't find any problem to write all what is required by your own.

Comment: Good catch on the selection change. I was looking for something similar.

Comment: @mike27015 Traditionally, I thought that these events were very unreliable, but Tim Williams proved me some weeks ago that I was completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Varocarbas already gave you a hint for the selection.
I can tell you how you can loop through the worksheets later on, the following code is done in C#.

```
foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in workbook.Sheets)
{
     workbook.Activate();
     if(sheet.Name="your specific selected row")
     {
            sheet.Activate();
     }
}
```

If you don't get it with C#, you get the VB.NET code behind here:

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/?batchId=bbd6bd81-5e7e-4341-8fb4-69830a87c654

Something similar for VB

```
Set excelApp = CreateObject("excel.application")
Set excelWrkbook = excelApp.WorkBooks.Add
Set excelSheet = excelWrkbook.WorkSheets(1)
excelSheet.Cells(1,1).Select //1,1 can be changed to be mapped on column A
```

Now with the code of Varocarbas, the C# and VB code, you should be able to do the link between all, and you should be able to click from Cell A -> event trigger or not and be able to compare the sheet name and activate the sheet according the StudentID.